# Comments custom fields access by role

Tags: entities, nodes, comments

Ive added a custom comment field to comments of my node i.e. new fields beneath comment_body that being field_flag_reason and field_unflag_reason

I want to hide these two fields for specific roles so I'm looking to use a hook with the logic to display when appropriate, the difficulty I'm having is I'm confused as to what element I should be trying to target in the rendered array and any changes I try don't seem to take effect, think I might be going about it the wrong way, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried [Field Permission](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions). I think it'll help to solve your requirements. Check the video tutorial to use that module [Drupal 7 Field Permissions Module](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmqlBBSoRWU)

Comment: Hey Stone Vo, looks like it might be what I'm needing Ill have a look and let you know. Cheers Jean

Comment: Works great cheers:)

Comment: You did that. Cheers :)